# Deprecation warning when using Compass Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass, compass

I am using the Compass gem for Rails. After installing it, I've used some mixins that come with Compass. I am getting a deprecation warning in the console:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING on line 87 of /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss: #{} interpolation near operators will be simplified
in a future version of Sass. To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:

  unquote('"$moz-"#{$experimental-support-for-mozilla} "$webkit-"#{$experimental-support-for-webkit} "$opera-"#{$experimental-support-for-opera} "$microsoft-"#{$experimental-support-for-microsoft} "$khtml-"#{$experimental-support-for-khtml}')

You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.
```

I am having trouble finding a fix for this online. What does this warning mean and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in the gem. Workaround until fix is pushed to gem here: https://github.com/Compass/compass/pull/2088

Comment: Thanks, this was annoying me too.